# Mapbox Map Pan Issue When Moving to Child Window

Tags: javascript, mapbox

I've got a case where we sometimes need to pop the map out of its main window into a child window.

I've tried this two ways: 1) destroying the map completely in the parent window, then reinitializing in a child window from the parent, and 2) by simply removing the map from the dom and appending to a child window as is done here: https://bl.ocks.org/benheb/0359091f537b559c12a908a63af77cbf

The issue is, that the map does not pan when in the child window, in either case. Zooming is smooth, all other functionality works, but panning is slow/does not work.

If you click to pan the map, then go back to the main parent window where the map used to live and move the mouse around, you'll note the map in the child window pans smoothly!

So somehow the pan event isn't getting disconnected from the parent? Is this something webgl related? Does anyone have a better solution for doing this? This is part of a bigger app, so it's not really feasible to reinitialize the app completely from the child window, as we need the parent window to still communicate/drive the data on the map.

GIF example: https://giphy.com/gifs/map-d3aCBN45ieb70fhm/fullscreen